# Text dont dissappear with media query

Tags: html, css

I have this working before but now it doesn't work but I don't find the way to fix it.

My HTML code is here:

```
<div class="discordRectangle flex flex-center w-220 h-100 rounded-xl shadow">
     <div class="iconleft"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></div>
    <div class="headerDiscord">
       <span class="small">CLICK TO JOIN OUR</span><br>
       <span class="big">OFFICIAL DISCORD &nbsp &nbsp</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code is here:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {  
  .small {
    color: white;
    font-size :0px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
  }
  
  .big {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

@media(min-width:1280px) {
  .small {
    color: white;
    font-size :12px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
  }
  
  .big {
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

I also tried with display: none; but it doesn't work anyways.

Any advice will be helpful, thanks beforehand.

Comment: Which media query do you want it to be hidden with? 768px or 1280px?

Comment: I assume that you want the text to display if width is greater than 1280px, but not display if it is between 768px and 1280px. Possibly the css properties are clashing is case of widths larger that 1280px; ie any width larger than 1280px is also larger than 768px and hence both styles are getting applied. You can try to apply like this: "@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1280px)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `visibility: hidden;` which is an alternative to `display: none;` I also changed your `min-width` to `max-width` cause it sounds like you want it hidden **below** that screen size. I also changed your media queries to `@media only screen` and because the **only** keyword is used to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles. The **and** is telling the browser at this maximum width I want this to happen to my elements.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {  
  .small {
    color: white;
    font-size :0px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .big {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) {
  .small {
    color: white;
    font-size :12px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
  }
  
  .big {
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One', cursive;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="discordRectangle flex flex-center w-220 h-100 rounded-xl shadow">
     <div class="iconleft"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></div>
    <div class="headerDiscord">
       <span class="small">CLICK TO JOIN OUR</span><br>
       <span class="big">OFFICIAL DISCORD &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the text is invisible and the div is still with the same amount of px because the text is there but invisible.

Comment: @FranciscoFlores Please see the adjusted code.